# Rails and email openened notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am developing an application on Rails and I need to know if its possible to write code which will notify me when the user opens an email that has been sent from my application (need to track this info) ?

The main bit of data I need is was it opened.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but there is no 100% certainty you will always get a notification.
SMTP has 2 standards, they are DSN and MDN. Both are in effect optional, there is no guarantee that the email system of the targeted email recipient (your user) will implement them too.

The easiest way is to pit in a `"Return-Receipt-To:"` (RRT) email header. Put some address as the content of the header. Now when a user opens an email message containing this header, the clients email reader will msot likely prompt your users whether or not to send a return receipt. If the do comply and email will be sent to the address you specified.
In Rails it could be something like:

```
themailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def notify_read
     headers['Return-Receipt-To:'] = 'notifyread@mysite.com'
     mail(:to => 'users@somecompany.com')
   end
end
```

You could just use an email address you monitor and read them manually OR you could set up rails to read these emails as well. But there is no guarantee you will ALWAYS get an acknowledgment.

Additionally you could check each email domain, many of the big free email providers have proprietary methods of requesting the return receipt. If you add `".readnotify.com"` onto the end of your recipients email address you will get a return receipt. You will have to research all the big ones though.
For example:

```
user@yahoo.com.readnotify.com
```

Hope that helps

*Source: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=147997#p147997*

Comment: There is no colon after the header name `headers['Return-Receipt-To'] = 'notifyread@mysite.com'`

Answer (score 0):

A common way of implenting this is to include a link to an invisible image file, with the link including sufficient details about the email for you to be able to identify which email is being viewed.

When the image is requested by the mail client, your server can then record the viewing attempt. If you use a 3rd party email provider (such as sendgrid, postageapp) then sometimes they'll do that for you and ping your server with the appropriate event. I strongly suspect that this is what readnotify  is doing under the hood (someone took the trouble of looking at this [a while ago](http://seclists.org/basics/2006/Jan/457)

This isn't completely accurate as some (many?) users turn off remote image viewing in their mail viewers.